# How to print only the filenames without their path in a txt file

Tags: linux, shell

```
Directory_Source/file1,file2,file3,file4
Directory_Target/Combined.txt
```

I tried: `ls Directory_Source/{file1,file3} > Directory_Target/Combined.txt`

but the result inside of the txt is  `Directory_Source/file1`,.....

Then tried with `ls -d */{file1,file3} > Directory_Target/Combined.txt`, same result.

Is it possible to achieve  what I seek without changing the command? What change do I have to commit.

Comment: Does `ls Directory_Source/{file1,file3} | sed 's#.*/##' > Directory_Target/Combined.txt` do what you want?

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._ There are other sites in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) better suited for this kind of questions, like Superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/209937/run-an-ls-without-getting-the-full-path

Comment: `basename` might come handy.

Comment: now it prints //file1, maybe must change {} to something else?

Comment: @MarcoLucidi How? I'm kind of new overall so I don't really know how to implement it in my example .

Comment: What do you mean with "now it prints //file1"... Please [edit] your question, copy&paste the new command and its output.

Comment: @AndreasCharitoudis e.g. `basename -a Directory_Source/{file1,file3} > Directory_Target/Combined.txt`

Comment: @Bodo I'm blind....well I missed one symbol, your solution worked. Thank you veryyy much.

Comment: @AndreasCharitoudis Don't add the solution/answer to the question. I made an answer from the two solutions proposed in comments. If you accept the answer by clicking the check mark, your question will be marked as answered. (You might have to wait some time before you can accept an answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions:

```
ls Directory_Source/{file1,file3} | sed 's#.*/##' > Directory_Target/Combined.txt
```

or

```
basename -a Directory_Source/{file1,file3} > Directory_Target/Combined.txt
```

See also https://superuser.com/q/209937/992527 for more solutions.